# Erro ao remover Objeto de uma ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Quando tento remover uma `int` da `arrayList` ele simplesmente da erro.

Codigo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add(Color.rgb(119, 103, 141)); colors.add(Color.rgb(33, 10, 208)); colors.add(Color.rgb(203, 100 ,180));
colors.add(Color.rgb(249, 0 ,193)); colors.add(Color.rgb(74, 169, 94)); colors.add(Color.rgb(25, 236, 70));
colors.add(Color.rgb(235, 213, 92)); colors.add(Color.rgb(242, 206, 9)); colors.add(Color.rgb(68, 243, 220));

int teste = colors.get(3);
colors.remove(teste);
```

Erro:

```
Process: lordlokon.contarapp, PID: 1840
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lordlokon.contarapp/lordlokon.contarapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-458559
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-458559
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:405)
        at lordlokon.contarapp.MainActivity.randomizar(MainActivity.java:63)
        at lordlokon.contarapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Seu ArrayList é de objetos Integer ou Color? dessa maneira vai dar erro.

Comment: @IronMan quando coloco `ArrayList<Color>` ele pede para mudar para `int`

Comment: Você está a tentar remover um item(indice = 3) que não existe. Os índices começão em `0`

Comment: @ramaral Eu adicionei 9 cores(0 a 8), por que não existe o índice 3 ??

Comment: Não reparei que havia mais de um `colors.add()` por linha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está em que o método `remove()` é sobrecarregado:

- [E remove(int index)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) - que remove o item baseado no index.
- [boolean remove(Object o)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) - que remove o item baseado no objecto guardado

O método [get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) retorna o objecto(*Integer* neste caso) guardado na posição indicada.
Como esse objecto é convertido para `int`(`int teste`) o método `remove()` a ser utilizado é aquele que espera um índice.

Repare nesta linha do erro:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-458559

Você está a tentar remover o índice *-458559*, que é o valor que o *ArrayList* tem na posição 3.(`Color.rgb(249, 0 ,193)`)

Uma forma possível de resolver será assim:

```
Integer teste = colors.get(3);
colors.remove(teste);
```

ou

```
int teste = colors.get(3);
colors.remove(colors.indexOf(teste));
```

Comment: Na variável `teste` eu não estou guardando o Objeto ?? poderia dar um exemplo usando o código que eu citei na pergunta ??

Comment: Ainda estou meio confuso, poderia me dar um exemplo ??

Comment: Consegui resolver, Obrigado.

Comment: Não sei se consigo explicar melhor. Se o ArrayList fosse do tipo `ArrayList<String>` o seu código não daria erro. O compilador iria utilizar o método `boolean remove(Object o)`